# How to add "use strict;" on first line when opening a new JavaScript file in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

How do I add the code `"use strict";` to always appear on Line 1 when opening a new JavaScript file?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me that you can do so without an extension (you could write a snippet and assign it a shortcut but that's not exactly what you want). There is, however, an extension that will do that for you:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=veekas.use-strict-everywhere